# Yii2: Theme not working

Tags: themes, yii2

I am using yii2 themes for the first time. I saw the themes to implement in yii2 through this link:[Yii2 theme factory](http://yii2.themefactory.net/)

According to the documentation, I downloaded the theme and installed it. I created a `themes` folder where I placed my themes.

This much I have done:
**In config/web.php file**

```
'components' => [
'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '.@wwwroot/themes/themes'],
                'baseUrl'   => '@www/themes/themes'
            ]
        ],
],
```

But, I am getting this kind of error:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'Invalid path alias: @www/themes/themes' in /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php:152
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Theme.php(99): yii\BaseYii::getAlias('@www/themes/the...')
#1 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(169): yii\base\Theme->setBaseUrl('@www/themes/the...')
#2 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(518): yii\base\Component->__set('baseUrl', '@www/themes/the...')
#3 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\base\Theme), Array)
#4 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(372): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\base\\Theme', Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\base\\Theme', Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(116): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#9 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(107): yii\base\View->init()
#10 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#11 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(372): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#12 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\web\\View', Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\web\\View', Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(133): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(554): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('view')
#16 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(228): yii\base\Application->getView()
#17 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(99): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderFile('@yii/views/erro...', Array)
#18 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(101): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\InvalidParamException))
#19 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\base\InvalidParamException))
#20 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'Invalid path alias: @www/themes/themes' in /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php:152
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Theme.php(99): yii\BaseYii::getAlias('@www/themes/the...')
#1 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(169): yii\base\Theme->setBaseUrl('@www/themes/the...')
#2 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(518): yii\base\Component->__set('baseUrl', '@www/themes/the...')
#3 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\base\Theme), Array)
#4 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(372): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\base\\Theme', Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\base\\Theme', Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(116): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#9 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(107): yii\base\View->init()
#10 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#11 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(372): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#12 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\web\\View', Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\web\\View', Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(133): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(554): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('view')
#16 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/Module.php(129): yii\base\Application->getView()
#17 [internal function]: yii\debug\Module->yii\debug\{closure}(Object(yii\base\Event))
#18 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(541): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(yii\base\Event))
#19 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(372): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeRequest')
#20 /var/www/html/scrum_tool/index.php(13): yii\base\Application->run()
#21 {main}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `@wwwroot` is not a valid path.

Try this if you are using basic app:

```
'components' => [
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/mytheme'],
            'baseUrl' => '@web/themePath',
        ],
    ],
],
```

More information [here](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/install-new-theme-in-yiiframework-2/)

Comment: I tried this but it is working normally. The home page is same as before. NO changes occurred

Comment: yes this worked but it create a horrible look to the website and gives this error:Bad Request (#400): Unable to verify your data submission. In the baseUrl I have added '@web/themes' because my theme folder is placed at root folder. Do I need to change the baseUrl path

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this

```
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'basePath' => '@wwwroot/themes/themes',
            'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@wwwroot/themes/themes'],
            'baseUrl'   => '@www/themes/themes'

        ],
    ],
```

and one common mistake is using it like the layouts folder instead of the views folder .Please beware of this and make a layouts folder in the @wwwroot/themes/themes if you are planing to override the layouts.